# Get statistics by hour with a limit of the 6 latest hours

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have a table called `uploads(id,file,date)` where `date` is a `DATETIME`,  i want to show a stats board in my website of the latest 6 hours uploads.

Something like:

```
13:00 : 12,200 Uploads
14:00 : 30,455 Uploads
15:00 : 15,202 Uploads
16:00 : 61,014 Uploads
17:00 : 55,104 Uploads
18:00 : 43,019 Uploads
```

Thanks

Comment: What kind of table? mySQL? MSSQL? SQLite? And what are you doing your query in? PHP? ASP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using:

```
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(u.date, '%H:00') AS hr,
         COUNT(*) AS numUploads
    FROM UPLOADS u
   WHERE u.date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 HOUR)
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(u.date, '%H:00')
ORDER BY hr
```

...will return:

```
hr     numUploads
------------------
13:00  12200
14:00  30455
15:00  15202
16:00  61014
17:00  55104
18:00  43019
```

### Caveats

- `NOW()` includes the time portion when the query was run.  Meaning, it could be 31 minutes past the hour, so the values likely will change for the last hour displayed.
- If there aren't any uploads though an entire hour that is in scope of the last six hours, it won't be displayed -- you'll need to LEFT JOIN to a table of derived time values to see a zero count.

## PHP

```
$query = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(u.date, '%H:00') AS hr,
                 COUNT(*) AS numUploads
            FROM UPLOADS u
           WHERE u.date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 HOUR)
        GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(u.date, '%H:00')"

$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo $row['hr'] .' : '. NUMBER_FORMAT($row['numUploads']) .' Uploads'
}
```

Comment: Also, do you have any idea of how to display the empty hours? where there is no uploads? i tested it and it skips the empty hours.

Comment: @David: Yes - I've demonstrated it in various questions under the [datetime-generation tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datetime-generation+mysql)